# Ruby Dir.exists? undefined method

Tags: ruby, dir, nomethoderror

I looked the `Dir.exists?` method up in the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-exist-3F) and I believe I am using it correctly, yet at each call I am hit with this error:

**undefined method `exists?' for Dir:Class (NoMethodError)**

Am I overlooking something incredibly obvious? Below is the related code.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
ARGV.each do |dir|          # Arguements are directory names.
    if !Dir.exists?(dir)
#dosomething
end
end
```

**EDIT:**

Using `File.directory?` instead of `Dir.exists?` fixes my program, yet does not explain this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version of Ruby are you using? The documentation link you provided is for Ruby 2.0. The `Dir.exists?` method [was not available in 1.8](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Dir.html).

You can check your Ruby version from the command line with:

```
ruby -v
```

Or from an IRB session, check the value of the `RUBY_VERSION` constant.

If you're interested in using newer/multiple Ruby versions on your machine, I recommend looking into [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/).

Comment: Just checked, I am on 1.8.7. That looks like it is the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I have the same persisting issue even though I used RVM o install an up to date ruby `$ ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]`. I am running on an ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine. Any ideas what may cause the issue?

Comment: @FMKerckhof: In the script where you are calling `Dir.exists?`, add a line like `puts "Ruby version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"` just to make sure it's running with the version of Ruby you installed with RVM.